# Can not remove . and .. using grep?

Tags: perl

I use readdir to get the files of a directory , but I want to remove . and .. using grep . The output shows it still contain the . and .. , but I can't figure out what's wrong with it ?

here is my code

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    opendir(Dir,$ARGV[0]);
    @Dirs = readdir(Dir);
    @Dirs = grep { $_ != /./ } @Dirs;
#   @Dirs = grep { $_ =~ /^./ } @Dirs;
    print join("\n",@Dirs);
```

Thanks

Comment: You might be wanting the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function instead.

Comment: That's an astounding typo you have there: `$_ != /./`. The numeric inequality operator `!=` will try to convert the file name to a string and (most likely) come up with `0`. The regex `/./` will match any file name, so will return `1` for "true". Since `0 != 1`, the grep seems to match anything, despite it being a cataclysmically erroneous thing to write. With `use warnings` on, you will get a nice warning: `Argument "foo.pl" isn't numeric in numeric ne (!=) at ...`. But if you, like you do, don't have warnings on, the error is silent and confusing.

Comment: Also, `my @files = <"$ARGV[0]">;` would work instead of `opendir` + `readdir` + `grep`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try escaping the `.`:

```
@Dirs = grep { $_ !~ /^\.\.?$/ } @Dirs;
```

The dot is a special metacharacter which matches any character when not escaped.

Comment: I find `grep not /\A [.]{1,2} \z/x, @Dirs` more readable. Also, note that `$` matches either the end of the string or before a newline. So, what happens if you have a file named `"..\n"`?

Answer (score 9):

I strongly suggest you take note of the following

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, even for the tiniest bit of code. They will repay you the extra typing time many times over
- *Always* use lexical directory handles and file handles. Global handles like this have been the 
  wrong choice for over twelve years now
- *Always* check the success of file and directory `open` calls, and use a `die` string that includes the `$!` variable to say *why* the open failed
- Use lower-case letters and underscores for local variable names. Upper case is reserved by  convention for global items like package names and built-in variables
- Use `print "$_\n" for @array` instead of `print join "\n", @array` because **a)** using `join` produces a second copy of the text in the array and wastes space, and **b)** using `join` omits the newline from the last line of the array

Take a look at this alternative to your program, which applies the advice above. I have excluded all directory entries beginning with a dot, as it successfully removes `.` and `..` as well as Linux "hidden" entries that start with a dot. You may require something different.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my $dh, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
my @dirs = grep { not /^\./ } readdir $dh;
print "$_\n" for @dirs;
```

Answer (score 2):

`.` in a regexp means "any character", try escaping it like this: `\.`